# Upload list state management in React

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-state-management

I am working on an UploadList component looking somewhat like this.

[image: upload list]

Every item in the list is a an Upload component. I am wondering how to manage the state for the whole UploadList. Obviously I can have a state like this.

```
[
  { fileName: 'File 1', progress: 'uploaded'},
  { fileName: 'File 2', progress: 'uploaded'}
  { fileName: 'File 3', progress: 60}
  { fileName: 'File 4', progress: 45}
  { fileName: 'File 5', progress: 'queued'}
  { fileName: 'File 6', progress: 'queued'}
]
```

But I expect the list to be quite long, say 100 items, and there will be at most 2 ongoing uploads. It seems wasteful to me to re-render the whole UploadList just to change progress of one item even with all the virtual DOM React magic. The ongoing uploads can be quite fast and the whole component would be constantly re-rendering.

Is the above approach a standard one and am I just over-optimizing? I very much like RxJS for state management and the above approach would just have one stream (observable) of values for the whole UploadList. Is there a standard way in RxJS to break the structure down so that I can have a stream for every ongoing upload so that only the ongoing uploads are re-rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making each file as a component? Create a component FileUploadComponent and render this component for each file in your upload list, something like:

```
uploadList.map((fileData) => (
<FileUploadComponent uploadProgress={fileData.uploadProgress} />))
```

This way I guess only the FileUploadComponent which is currently uploading will re-render.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing. Since the whole state is managed by the UploadList component, whenever that state changes, the whole component re-renders. That is how React works I believe. It of course does not re-render those children who did not change, but that is reconciliation and too me even doing that is too much work. But maybe this is how it is supposed to work.